# Remove date field from annotation in PDFTron

Tags: pdftron

How to remove the date from the annotation form?[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVemq.png)

Comment: Show your efort also

Comment: Can't found any related API even to try

Comment: You want to edit the PDF, so that date does not appear, or you want to edit the viewer so the date doesn't appear? If the former, what language are you coding in? If the latter, which viewer (Web, Android, etc.) are you using?

Comment: I'm using PDFTron webviewer, the project is React js based. One of tasks is to hide the date (modified/created) in the annotations' sidebar menu.